# Windows based Virtual Modem software

Tags: modem, sip

I am trying to find a virtual software that will allow multiple users to "dial in" to a machine at any given time. However my efforts have been stopped at every step of the way. The phone number we would like to use is a VoIP line, that'll redirect the traffic to the machine using SIP (since my house does not actually have physical POTS jacks.

Anyone have an idea of any software that could be used to provide a solution to this?

---

edit

---

I have used 2 separate pieces of software.

- Virtual Modem Pro by Eltima Software
- FabulaTech Virtual Modem

I even tried T.38 Fax and Voice Modem, which does not work for what we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea.  VOIP is not designed for what you are trying to do, and if you have VOIP you already have Internet, so you should be using a virtual terminal or Internet enabled solution.

If you do need to go with VOIP, you will need to ensure you use alaw or ulaw codecs so the data is not compressed.  Also expect it to be hideously slow as its just not designed to work with data connections, things like jitter (changes in latency for each packet) and packet loss play havock with data connections.

I believe T.38 won't help much as its almost a store-and-forward protocol, done in near realtime.

Comment: I've read all over the internet that this is a bad idea, but it is really our only solution to allow users in remote areas to still connect to the services they need to use. Most of our people in remote areas don't have internet in the area and this is truly the only way to connect them.

Comment: If they don't have Internet, they should get a dialup Internet account from a dialup provider and connect across that.   At least the modem is then getting the cleanest possible signal and the data is being converted into packets which can traverse a normal network.  If its that important you can always create a dialup system using POTS or ISDN lines and run your own "mini isp".

Comment: That's essentially what we're trying to do but a private ISP. So in order for us to do this we'd need more physical hardware.